# Macbook Pro 15'' early 2011 - external monitor 27'' with DVI connection

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport, hardware-recommendation

I want to buy an external monitor for my Macbook Pro (15'' early 2011). I would want a 27'' with 2560x1440 resolution but I have a doubt:
a mini diplay port/DVI converter is sufficient or I will need this one? Mini DisplayPort/Dual-Link DVI http://www.apple.com/it/shop/product/MB571Z/A/adattatore-da-mini-displayport-a-dvi-dual-link

the description of the adapter says:

> Use the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter to connect your Mac to a 30-inch display that includes a DVI connector, such as the 30-inch Apple Cinema Display HD, and enjoy the ultimate widescreen canvas with a resolution of 2560 by 1600 pixels.

Hardware specs for my model say (https://support.apple.com/kb/SP620?locale=it_IT&viewlocale=en_US):

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors

Thank you for your anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a resolution of 2560x1440 and you want to use DVI, then you ***must*** use a Dual Link DVI adapter.  Period.  A Single Link DVI connector will only support up to 1920x1200.

That said, I wouldn't recommend going with Dual Link DVI but rather getting a monitor that natively support Display Port or mini Display Port like the Dell UltraSharp U2715H

[image]

I am a big proponent of the idea that the less you have to convert, the better the reliability.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer; my Macbook has the thunderbolt port, so I think that a miniDP /DP cable would be sufficient, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct

Answer (score 0):

I've got MBP Early 2013, 13" and just bought Eizo 2750, 27" with 2660x1440 resolution. First I've tried it to connect it through mini Display Port -> adapter -> DVI D -> HDMI (I do not have mini Display to HDMI cable yet). With above config I'v achieved that resolution, though with refresh rate 30Hz, which is not acceptable for longer work. 
Than I'v tried a cable mini Diplay Port -> Display Port and it works great with 60Hz, only strange thing that it uses NTSC not PAL, but see no difference.
So you don't know until you try, imho the best solution is to go to the store with the laptop and bunch of cables and ask to try chosen display :) remember to check not only resolution you've got but also refresh rate, at least 60Hz (59 on NTSC) is a minimum for decent work